# Howto reduce cpu resources for Custom DefaultTableCellRenderer (zebra color table)?

Tags: jtable

I have table in program and I design Zebra color table using class:

```
private class ColorTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        final Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        table.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0,0));
        if(!isSelected) {
            if (row%2 == 0) {
                cellComponent.setBackground(new Color(255,255,254));
            } else {
                cellComponent.setBackground(new Color(170,170,170));
            }
        }
        return cellComponent;
    }
}
```

when call that class with :

```
mytable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new ColorTableCellRenderer());
```

need very big cpu resources(about 50%). 
And when using DefaultTableCellRenderer, call with:

```
mytable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer());
```

Need only 1% cpu resources. 
I try using this:

```
private class ColorTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    JTable table = new JTable()
    {
        @Override
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
        {
            Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
            table.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0,0));
            System.out.println("Coba ");
            //  Alternate row color
            if(row%2 == 0) {
                c.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            else {
                c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
            return c;
        }
    };
}
```

Nothing happened (failed).
Maybe someone can fix ColorTableCellRenderer class above to reduce using cpu resources. Thanks.

Comment: Browsing through the code of `table.setIntercellSpacing`, you can see that this function does **a lot** of stuff. It fires some events, causes revalidation and repaint... My first hint would be to remove this call from the renderer, and instead, call this method *once*, directly on the table, probably directly before calling `setDefaultRenderer`.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If so, I think that the question could be closed or deleted (or I could try to turn the comment into an answer, but ... meh...)

Comment: Yes, your comment give me solution.